# lambda foreach add to map not working

Tags: java, javafx-8

I got the following variables

```
List<Pruefvorschrift> listP = new ArrayList<Pruefvorschrift>();
ObservableMap<TestDevice,List<Pruefvorschrift>> testDev = FXCollections.emptyObservableMap();
```

in one function i want to fill the testDev by using lambda expression

```
//first call REST service and get data
List<TestDevice> test_dev = call.getTestDevice("");
//now do a foreach to add each entry (as key) to the testDev ObservableMap with a empty List (as value)
test_dev.stream().forEach(td ->{
                    TestDevice t = td;                    
                    testDev.put(t, listP);
            });
```

but all i get is a error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)

which obviously is this row

```
 testDev.put(t, listP);
```

maybe i misunderstood the new stream api but i only want to fill the observable map with all the result of the call (key) and an empty List (value which will be modified later).
Any help? Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever `Map` type is returned by [`FXCollections#emptyObservableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#emptyObservableList%28%29)

```
FXCollections.emptyObservableMap();
```

does not support the `put` method. You can't add anything to it. As the javadoc states

> Creates and[sic] empty **unmodifiable** observable list.

This has nothing to do with lambda expressions or the `Stream` api.

Answer (score 0):

just to complete here (Sotirios Delimanolis was absolute right and me so wrong :). My problem was solved by doing a correct job with the map itself

```
//create empty map
Map<TestDevice,List<Pruefvorschrift>> map = new HashMap<TestDevice,List<Pruefvorschrift>>();
//use this map to create the ObservableMap
ObservableMap<TestDevice,List<Pruefvorschrift>> testDev = FXCollections.observableMap(map);
```

And all works...Thx Sotirios